# Netbeans & Subversion: how to exclude/ignore a library that's been included in the project's path when commiting?

Tags: svn, netbeans, commit, ignore

I can't find any option in netbeans or answer about this issue.

Basically, I've included a library to a project's path, then the only option I've got if I right-click that 'include_path' folder is properties, and then there's another option there called 'Ignored_folders'.

The library that I'm including and the project are in different locations, as that library is shared by several projects.

When I try to add that library to the 'ignored_folders' I get the following error:

**Folder ".ZendFramework-1.11.11" is not underneath Source/Tests/Selenium directory.**

I read in the Netbeans documentation that by default all folders starting by dot (.) are ignored, but this doesn't seem to be the case for me. If I try to commit anything, that folder is still taken into account.

Any idea what could be happening and how to exclude such a library?